# FTP 550: Permission Denied

Tags: ssh, permissions, ftp

I suddenly get the error 550: Permission Denied in Filezilla when I try to create a new directory.

A few days ago I changed some settings on the server regarding ssl and imap settings, but I don't think this has affected the FTP settings ...

Anyhow, after long googling nothing seems to work. The main idea could be that the user hasn't got permissions, but the interesting thing is that I can:

- create files
- delete files
- delete directories

But not creating directories. I get the error "550 Permission denied" in the main directory and "550 access_log: No such file or directory" in the subdirectory.

Anyone knows where the error could be? Thanks

Comment: maybe sometimes there is a file name restriction and the file name didn't meet the requirement

Answer (score 6):

1, Add the following parameters in your `vsftpd.conf` to give permission to anonymous user or script in your Linux machine. The `vsftpd.conf` may be located in `/etc/vsftpd.conf`.

```
write_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
```

2, Restart ftp service in your server.

```
sudo systemctl restart vsftpd
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are on Linux, Go up one directory, and see if the user has permissions there.  For example:

Try setting the permissions on the directory to 777.  If it works you know you have a problem with the permissions.  DO NOT leave the directory at 777, it is not secure, just for quick testing.  755 is usually appropriate if you have everything set up correctly.  You can also try adding the user to the group that owns the directory (you can do this through ls -l).  This will tell you what user owns that.

Comment: For a directory 644 would be a bad mode, since it lacks `x` and the directory cannot be entered!

Comment: You are absolutely right, I was getting my file and folder settings confused.

Comment: This will return it back:
find ./ftp-dir/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {}\;
_____
find ./ftp-dir/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {}\;

Answer (score 2):

I got a 550 using FTP with Filezilla because regular FTP didn't have high enough permissions on my server.

I switched to an SSH/SFTP connection and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Filezilla project has a good piece on [Securing your Windows Service installation](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Securing_your_Windows_Service_installation). In essence:

**Create User**

1. Close the Filezilla interface (if open)
2. Stop the Filezilla service
3. Create a User level (not Administrator level) Windows account for FileZilla service to run under, with "password never changes"
4. In Services, open Filezilla properties, Log On tab and change to run with the new account

**Folder Permissions**

5. Give Write permissions to the new user on `C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla Server\FileZilla Server.xml`
6. If you use logging, set "Write" access to `C:\Windows\Logs`
7. On target FTP upload folders set "Full Control" to each topmost writable folder you want to use

**Restart Service**

Answer (score 0):

If someone ended here searching for `Command: PWD Response: 550 PWD: Permission denied` instead, check the for the presence of `.ftpaccess` file in the home dir, in my case it was causing the error.